# win api MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx dwMilliseconds Как сделать что бы Milliseconds всегда выполнял обратный отсчет? он зависает а время вышло

Tags: delphi, winapi

Я использую MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx что бы получать в потоке сообщения и их обрабатывать.
я думал что тайм аут работает всегда как обычно и для меня это важно что бы MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx выходила строго по определенному время но оказалось что она как вздумается иногда зависнет иногда норм отработает в доках нашел причину этого теперь не могу понять какая есть альтернатива что тайм аут всегда вел отсчет.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-msgwaitformultipleobjectsex

> Windows XP, Windows Server 2003, Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 и Windows Server > 2008 R2:   значение dwMilliseconds включает время, проведенное в режимах пониженного энергопотребления. Например, тайм-аут продолжает обратный отсчет, пока компьютер спит.

> Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 10 и Windows Server > 2016:   значение dwMilliseconds не включает время, проведенное в режимах пониженного > энергопотребления . Например, тайм-аут не отсчитывается, пока компьютер находится в спящем режиме.

использую в коде ее примерно так

```
        while not Terminated and not Quit do
        begin

          Ms:= MiliSecondsTimeOutWaitFor;
          log('HandleThread ms ='+ms.ToString);
          dwResult := MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx(1, aEvent, Ms, QS_ALLINPUT, MWMO_INPUTAVAILABLE );

          case dwResult of
            WAIT_OBJECT_0    :begin
                               Quit:=Quit;
                             end;

            WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1:  begin PeekProcMessage; end;
            WAIT_TIMEOUT     :  begin DoTimeOutWaitFor; end;
          end;

        end;
```

Comment: А какого порядка у вес величина таймаута? Десятки минут? 1. Запретить переход компьютеру в спящий режим. 2. таймауты сделать намного короче и вручную считать реальный таймаут. 3. искать варианты дальше.

Comment: @Vlad Chapl могут быть и 1 сек и 1 день такой ранж  с какойго значения начинаются длинные таймы? 10мин или 1 час или сколько?

Comment: @vegat4, [WaitableTimer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sync/using-waitable-timer-objects) пробовал? К сожалению, сам на данный момент времени проверить не могу.

Comment: К примеру тебе нужна точность 5 секунд, а таймаут 1 час. В функцию MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx передаем таймаут 5000 мс, перед первым вызовом запоминаем текущее время. После каждого срабатывания WAIT_TIMEOUT смотрим сколько реально прошло времени. Если меньше, чем нам хочется, то снова запускаем MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx. Хотя это костыль, лучше найти нормальное решение.

Comment: @Vlad Chapl
ну так если комп заснул то 5 сек будут идти вечность

Comment: а после пробуждения не возобновляется??? по замыслу разработчиков отсчет должен продолжаться после выхода из спячки.